# Limit permitted integer values for serialised class property with Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, enums, gson

I'd like to limit the permitted integer values for a class property, in a way that after serialisation to Json (with [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)) the value would be represented as a number and not as a string.

```
class Car(
@Expose val color: Color = Color.RED,
@Expose val seats: Seats = Seats.FIVE   // Using an enum class so only predefined values are accepted.
)

enum class Color{
     @SerializedName("red") RED,
     @SerializedName("blue") BLUE,
}

enum class Seats{
     @SerializedName("4") FOUR,
     @SerializedName("5") FIVE,
}
```

Actual json output:

```
{
   "color": "red",
   "seats": "5"   // This is a string. It's not what I want.
}
```

The json output I need:

```
{
   "color": "red",
   "seats": 5   // This is a number ✓
}
```

Comment: As a side note, what's the reason behind the choice of Gson as a serialization library? It's in maintenance mode now, and is not very well suited for Kotlin. I'd advise using [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) or [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) (the successor of Gson) instead

Comment: @Joffrey Thanks for the heads-up. I am using gson because that's just what my code had implemented many years ago, and I didn't want the overhead of ripping it out and replacing it.

Comment: @Joffrey Would you say kotlinx.serialization is more future-proof to switch to compared to Moshi given that's part of Kotlin?

Comment: Yes, it's also Kotlin-first so future features will probably be supported better out of the box. Note that the approach is quite different too. Kotlinx Serialization generates serializers at compile time, while Moshi is reflection-based by default (although it does support codegen as well IIRC). Also Kotlinx Serialization is multiplatform, while Moshi is JVM only at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to stick to Gson, one way of doing this is to specify the integer as a property of the enum:

```kotlin
enum class Seats(val value: Int) {
    FOUR(4),
    FIVE(5);

    companion object {
        fun of(value: Int) = entries.firstOrNull { it.value == value }
    }
}
```

Then use a type adapter or custom serializer that uses this property for serialization, and the `Seat.of(...)` function for deserialization:

```kotlin
class SeatSerializer : JsonSerializer<Seats> {
    override fun serialize(src: Seats, typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement =
        JsonPrimitive(src.value)
}

class SeatDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Seats> {
    override fun deserialize(element: JsonElement, type: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Seats =
        Seats.of(element.asInt) ?: error("Cannot deserialize ${element.asInt} as Seats")
}
```